# How to get the List of Users registered in James Server through JMX

Tags: java, grails, groovy, jmx, james

I have configured the James server and added some user and domains to it.

From the Jconsole i am able to get the list of users as shown in below image.

Can anyone please provide me the code snippet to get same through the **JMX**

as James documentation specify this [To add user Programatically by JMX](http://james.apache.org/server/3/manage.html#Manage_via_JMX)

Somehow i manage to get the code snippet work but unable to find how to call the operations of Mbean without any parameter.

This code is printing attributes of Mbean

```
    String url = "service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi";
    JMXServiceURL serviceUrl = new JMXServiceURL(url);
    JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl, null);
    try {
        MBeanServerConnection mbeanConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("org.apache.james:type=component,name=usersrepository");
        MBeanInfo info = mbeanConn.getMBeanInfo(mbeanName);
        MBeanAttributeInfo[] attributes = info.getAttributes();
        for (MBeanAttributeInfo attr : attributes)
        {
            System.out.println(attr.getDescription() + " " + mbeanConn.getAttribute(mbeanName,attr.getName()));
        }
    } finally {
        jmxConnector.close();

    }
```

Please help in getting this code work to get the Users List.

[image: This is the Jconsole screen for getting the Users list from James Server]

Answer (score 0):

When invoking operations on a bean via JMX, the calls are proxied through the MBeanServer. You request that the MBeanServer invokes some method on a managed bean with the ObjectName. In your code, you access the MBeanServer through a MBeanServerConnection.

To invoke a blank method you would:

```
MBeanServerConnection mbeanConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("org.apache.james:type=component,name=usersrepository");

// since you have no parameters, the types and values are null
mbeanConn.invoke(mbeanName, "MethodToInvoke", null, null)
```

Using the MBeanServer to invoke methods can be cumbersome, so it might be easier to use a JMX Proxy Object. This just has the local connection construct a java.lang.reflect.Proxy object that uses the MBeanServerConnection.invoke method in it's InvocationHandler. Then you can use the Proxy object like a normal instance of your class. For this approach, your target MBean has to implement an interface that you can use to generate the local proxy.

```
import javax.management.JMX;
import org.apache.james.user.api.UsersRepository;
...

UsersRepository proxy = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbeanConn, mbeanName, UsersRepository.class);
Iterator<String> userList = proxy.list();
```

Either one of these ways should allow you to invoke methods without or without parameters on the user repository bean.